# Need command to print out filename but not the preceeding directory paths

Tags: bash, directory

Currently it prints out `/dir1/dir2/dir3/filename`

I just want it to print out just the `filename` "without" the directory paths.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should tell us what "it" is, which language "it" is written in and probably also the OS on which you are running "it".

Comment: sorry, bash on linux

Comment: You should add this information to your question by editting it. I've added a tag for you, which will mean that people can actually find it.

Comment: did you tried basename? e.g. basename /dir1/dir2/dir3/filename

Answer (score 1):

The question is extremely vague, but assuming that you've got a Bash command like

```
echo "$path"
```

you can print just the file name with

```
echo "${path##*/}"
```

`echo` can do unexpected things when used with variable strings, so a better alternative is

```
printf '%s\n' "${path##*/}"
```

Comment: Thank you @pjh for the helpful tip :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do but

```
ls /path/to/files > /path/to/output
```

Say you have 3 individual text files in the directory, the above will combine all 3 files each filename on one line without the actual path.

Hope that helps

**Bash alternative**

```
for file in /path/to/files/*.txt; do
 echo ${file##*/} >> /path/to/output/filename.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

use [basename](http://ss64.com/bash/basename.html) for that like this:

```
shortpath=$(pwd)
basename "$shortpath"
```

Comment: Note that, with Bash, you can avoid the cost of running a subprocess by using `$PWD` instead of `$(pwd)`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this using awk

| awk '{(n=split($18,a,"/")); print $6, $10, $8,a[n], "\n"}' > /sometextfile.txt

"\n" was because I needed a blank line between the results.